# Split nvarchar into to extract integer values in MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, nvarchar

I have 2 columns:

```
Duration     |  ID  
0h 7m 55sec. |  1
0h 25m 33sec.|  2
10h 5m 5sec. |  3
4h 11m 31sec.|  4
```

Duration(nvarchar(255))
I want to calculate the Duration in TOTAL NUMBER OF SECONDS for each ID.
I tried using SUBSTRING and then CAST but it's not giving me the desired output. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: SUBSTRING and then CAST is the way to do it, share what you have?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for validating that. But the issue is, I'm not sure how to split the nvarchar on 'h' 'm' 's'
When I'm using Substring(Duration, 4,CharIndex('m',Duration))
It gives me for example 7m 55 instead of just 7

Comment: Once again, post what you have, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for MySQL, as the question was originally tagged.

Yuck.  But you can do:

```
select (substring_index(col, 'h ', 1) * 60 * 60 +
        substring_index(substring_index(col, 'm ', 2), ' ', -1) * 60 + 
        substring_index(substring_index(col, 'sec.',1),' ', -1)
       ) as duration_secs
from t;
```

This extracts each component and then uses implicit conversion for the calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon Linoff. Can you please suggest a way of doing the same on Sql server?

Comment: @Pradeep Yadav...  please tag your question as SQL Server if you want a SQL Server answer - it is currently tagged at MySQL.

Comment: @RMathis I was trying to perform the same operation on both MySQL and SQL server. But I have added a tag for SQL server now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The query below is using str_to_date to cast the string, the time_to_sec function is converting the time portion to seconds.

This approach will break if duration exceeds 23h 59m 59sec.  @Gordon Linoff's approach will handle that scenario.

```
select id,
       duration,
       time_to_sec(str_to_date(duration,'%Hh %im %ssec.')) as seconds_elapsed;
```